# ReactJS: How to add an existing array to another array using react hooks? (CLOSED)

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to add an array to an existing array using react hooks. The only problem I have is everything I try it keeps not filling the array...

`const [ residenceFinal, setResidenceFinal ] = useState([]);`

I created the the value here and beneath I am trying to add an existing array to residenceFinal.

```
const predefinedMenuItems = {
      residences: {
            closeOnClick: false,
            setActiveOnClick: true,
            tooltip: "Residences",
            content: <i className='fas fa-city'/>,
            onClick: () => {
                dispatch(getValue(value));
            },
            getContent: (controlledEntity) => {
                const divTitle = "Residence info";

                let res = controlledEntity.info;
                const {data} = res;
                let residencesInfo = [];
                _.isArray(data) ? residencesInfo = data : residencesInfo.push(data);

                let resiFinal = residencesInfo.map(function(el) {
                    var o = Object.assign({}, el);
                    o.isActive = false;
                    return o;
                  })

                setResidenceFinal(resiFinal);
                return <div className="open-data-information-drawer-item residences">
                    <h1>{divTitle}</h1>
                    <div className="open-data-item-information-container">
                        {residenceFinal.map((residence, idx) => {
                            return <div className={"open-data-item-information-container-item "+ (residence.isActive ? 'active' : '') + " item-" + idx}  onClick={ (e) => onClickIdentification(residence, idx)} key={idx}>
                                {getOpenDataLi(residence, "identificatiecode")}
                                {getOpenDataLi(residence, "status")}
                                {getOpenDataLi(residence, "oppervlakte")}
                        }
                            </div>;
                        })}
                    </div>
                </div>;

            }
       }
}
```

So I have tried alot of variations to add resiFinal to residenceFinal (naming is gonna change when i fixed it btw) but every time I check, the residenceFinal is still empty...

Can somebody help me?

Edit: added where the getContent is used.

```
const [ drawerContent, setDrawerContent ] = useState(<div></div>);
```

```
function handleClick(index, e) {
        const selectedMenuItem = menuItems.find(m => m.id === index);

        setDrawerContent(selectedMenuItem.getContent(openData));
    }
```

```
<List.Item >
    <div key={predefinedMenuItemId} onClick={ e => handleClick(predefinedMenuItemId, e)}  className={isMenuItemActive ?  'list-item list-item-' + predefinedMenuItemId  : 'list-item list-item-' + predefinedMenuItemId }></div>
</List.Item >
```

Comment: Did you `consoel.log()` the values for `residencesInfo` adn `resiFinal` variables like right before `setResidenceFinal(resiFinal)`?

Comment: try: `setResidenceFinal([...resiFinal]);` but correct way to set state is:

`setResidenceFinal([... residenceFinal, ...resiFinal]);` persist the previous state as well.

Comment: Most likely `controlledEntity.info.data` is an empty array.

Comment: It's not clear what your code is supposed to do. Where is `getContent` used and when is it called? Also a getter usually is side-effect-free meaning it doesn't change the applications state when called. But that may be just due to bad naming. If your goal is to append `resiFinal` to the current state then it's just: `setResidenceFinal(current => [...current, ...resiFinal]);`

Comment: @trixn I edited my post with where the getContent is used.

Comment: Are you sure you want to pass predefinedMenuItemId in handleClick? 

handleClick(predefinedMenuItemId, e)

You were supposed to pass an index (number) but you are passing the entire predefinedMenuItems object.

Comment: Your code is very confusing and I guess you have a misconception about how react state works. For example you do `setDrawerContent(selectedMenuItem.getContent(openData));` but `getContent()` doesn't actually return anything but it sets another state as a side effect. So it always returns `undefined`.

Comment: @trixn my bad, edited the post with what it returns. I am new to react yes, sorry!

Comment: @TimoterHuurne Oh now is see the problem. You should not set state with what you actually want to render. The only thing that should return jsx is your render function. State should only contain plain data and your render function renders it accordingly when the state changes. There are so many issues with that code that I'm affraid to say you should go back to the basics first and follow a good tutorial on how to render stateful components.

Comment: @trixn will do, thanks for the help :)

Comment: @TimoterHuurne Sorry I couldn't help out more but it would exceed the length of a stackoverflow answer and the scope of that question to fix all the issues. The answer to your orgiginal question still is: `setResidenceFinal(current => [...current, ...resiFinal])`to append `resiFinal` to your current state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to employ Spread Syntax

example of how it works:

```
var colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue'];
var refColors = [...colors, 'yellow'];
//colors => ['red', 'green', 'blue']
//refColors => ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow']
```

So for your case

```
setResidenceFinal(current => [...current, ...resiFinal])
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you can add array to existing array

- push() method
- spread operator
- concat() method

```js
let array = [1,2];
array.push(...[3,4])
console.log(array)

let array2 = [10,11];
let newArray = [...array2, ...[12,13]];
console.log(newArray)

let array3 = [20,21];
let newArray2 = [22,23].concat(...array3)
console.log(newArray2)
```

you can add using such ways.

```
setResidenceFinal([...residenceFinal, ...resiFinal]);
```

> Recommended to use spread operator for updating state in react

Comment: While this is correct, `push` is not good practice to use for state-updates with React as that does mutate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to achieve this:

`setResidenceFinal([... residenceFinal, ...resiFinal]);`

As told you in my comment above, it's the correct way to set the state, preserving previous state while adding new state. One should never **mutate** the state directly.